# Solving nonlinear system of equations for variables

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I would like to solve the following system of equations for $α_1$ and $α_2$:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\alpha_1 sin(\alpha_1 +\alpha_2)-sin(\alpha_1) \alpha_1 +sin(\alpha_1) \alpha_2}{\alpha_1 \alpha_2}\\
\frac{-\alpha_1 cos(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)+cos(\alpha_1)\alpha_1+\alpha_2-\alpha_2 cos(\alpha_1)}{\alpha_1 \alpha_2}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Obviously, this is not straight forward. The equations describe a Cartesian robotic end-effector position depending on the two angles $α_1$ and $α_2$. I would like to get your feedback how to proceed.

1.) Is there an analytic solution to compute $α_1$ and $α_2$ for a given $x$ and $y$?

2.) If not, would you try to fit an approximation around the working point?

3.) Is there any other approach I don't have in mind?

Every feedback is appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Usually, when you have both angle and a trigonometric function of the angle, the only way to solve it is numerically.

Comment: @Moo - Yes, I thought of Newton's Method and yes there are periodic roots. I hoped for any more elegant solution. Thanks, for your feedback.

Comment: @Andrei - that's what I guessed - I just hoped someone might know a better solution. Thanks though!!